# How to get newly created User's userId (cannot be current user)?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am begginer in Firebase and my problem is:

I have to get one user id of any of the recently added users but the user can't be the current user.

Until now I have done this but it isnt working.

```
 DatabaseReference databaseusers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    Query query=databaseusers.limitToLast(50);


    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if(!snapshot.getValue().toString().equals(currentuseruid)){

                    player2uid=snapshot.getValue().toString();
                }

            }
```

[image: here is the structure of the database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getKey()` to get a node's key

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    if (!snapshot.getKey().equals(currentuseruid)) {
        player2uid = snapshot.getKey();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I need to get the user id not the name

Comment: @TincoDeSimone ah I see. Then we need to use `getKey()` method instead to get the user id.

Comment: But , getKey method is not only for push keys?In case is not I would thank you if you show me how I can do

Comment: The getKey() method that you mentioned is from [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#getKey()) which is used to get the push key string. We're using DataSnapshot's getKey() for this, [the reference page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getKey())

Comment: Yes, but the user id is from FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser.getUid, not from push.

Comment: yes I know, for the "currentuseruid", right? can you explain in detail which part you don't understand from my answer? and have you tried to run it?

Comment: Yes, I tried, player2uid never gets assigned.What I mean if getKey is for getting the keys of push and this key is from Firebase auth, I dont know if it is going to get it.

Comment: please mark my answer as the answer. :)
note that there's a difference between [DatabaseReference.getKey()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#getKey()) and [DataSnapshot.getKey()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getKey())

Comment: Do you have any idea why it isnt working?, should i reestructure the database?